# XmlWriter invalid colon character

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I'm building some xml using XmlWriter using a valid xml file as my template. In the file, I have this line: `<ds:Signature>`

So, I did this in C#:
`writer.WriteStartElement("ds:Signature");`

But it gives me an error of invalid character 0x3A, which is a colon. Is there a way for me to build that line of xml using XmlWriter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, "ds" refers to an xml namespace, and in correct XML you can't use it without declaring it, either in a node or one of its ancestors, earlier in the file.

`XmlWriter` is aware of namespaces, forces you to create correct XML. It remembers namespaces when you use them.

This means that you can do the following:

```
using (var x = XmlWriter.Create("test.xml"))
{
    x.WriteStartElement("ds", "ParentNode", "namespace");
    x.WriteStartElement("ds", "Signature", "namespace");
    x.WriteEndElement();
    x.WriteEndElement();
    x.Flush();
    x.Close();
}
```

which will produce the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ds:ParentNode xmlns:ds="namespace">
    <ds:Signature />
</ds:ParentNode>
```

This tells somebody reading the xml that "ParentNode" and "Signature" are defined in the namespace "namespace", which is assigned the prefix "ds" by the `xmlns:ds="namespace"` attribute.

This is pretty useful, but if you want something simpler, and you just want to spit out text, I'd say just use a `StreamWriter`:

```
using (var s = new StreamWriter("test.xml"))
{
    s.WriteLine("<ds:Signature>");
    s.Flush();
    s.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a correct answer and additionally for the StreamWriter suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("wp","wxr_version", null);
```

To get this result:

```
<wp:wxr_version>
```